# get the id of questions seperatly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the question id in a loop

```
<div class = "y">
 <% @slno = 0 %>
 <%- @answers.each do |b| -%>
   <% @slno= @slno + 1 %>
  <div class = "label_field_pair">
      <label for "questions">
          <%= @slno %> ) <%= b.ques %>
      </label>  <br>
    <div class = "label_field_pair2">
      <label for "options">
        <%= radio_button_tag "question#{b.id}", "#{b.id}ans1"%><%= b.ans1  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "question#{b.id}", "#{b.id}ans2"%><%= b.ans2  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "question#{b.id}", "#{b.id}ans3"%><%= b.ans3  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "question#{b.id}", "#{b.id}ans4"%><%= b.ans4  %>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<div id = "submit_button">
<%= submit_tag "", :value => "Submit" %>
</div>
</div>
```

here it displayed questions... I want the id of the question separately for each

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do, but you may try something like this:

```
  <label for "options">
    <% (1..4).each do |answer_id|
      <%= radio_button_tag "question#{b.id}", "#{b.id}ans#{answer_id}"%><%= b.send("ans#{answer_id}")  %>
    <% end %>
  </label>
```

Comment: No i get the value of radio button using params[:question].. i got question1 => ans1,question2 => ans2 like that.. for this many questions are displayed how can i get the id of questions seperatly